# Generic method returning an object instance of T

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have same classes but in different namespaces. ex: x.InHeaderType, y.InHeaderType etc...

I have to create instances of these classes with same parameters frequently.

Here is a sample:

```
x.InHeaderType inHeader = new x.InHeaderType();

inHeader.CompanyId = "TEST";
inHeader.UserId = "TEST";
inHeader.Password = "TEST";
inHeader.MessageId = " ";
```

Is it possible to create a method like:

```
    public static T GetInHeaderProperty<T>()
    {
        T value;
        // fill the properties of object and return the instance of T
        // I will call it when I need x.InHeaderType or y.InHeaderType
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you have such duplication? If you eliminate it, your problem is solved.

Comment: What @Oded said. Or, do they at least share a common base class you could use?

Comment: In fact they are not my classes, they are coming from several service references.

Comment: Are they endpoints that you have control over (e.g. in-house code?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
public static T GetInHeaderProperty<T>() where T : new()
{
    dynamic result = new T();
    result.CompanyId = "Test";
    result.UserId = "Test";
    result.Password = "Test";
    result.MessageId = " ";
    return (T)result;
}
```

This is a simplified version of Tomas Jansson's answer. It assumes that all the types have a default constructor.

You can call it like this:

```
var result = GetInHeaderProperty<x.InHeaderType>();
```

Answer (score 8):

First of, why do you have the same class in two differente namespaces?

I would create somekind of magic function like:

```
public static T GetInHeaderProperty<T>(Func<T> createObjFunc)
{
    T result = createObjFunc();
    dynamic resultAsDynamic = result as dynamic;
    resultAsDynamic.CompanyId = "Test";
    resultAsDynamic.UserId = "Test";
    resultAsDynamic.Password = "Test";
    resultAsDynamic.MessageId = " ";
    return (T)result;
}
```

That might work, but I'm not sure I would recommend it. You might have some other kind of issue with your code forcing you to do things like this that you should fix first.

**UPDATE:** I made the assumption that you can't make the objects inherit the same interface. If they can you should definitely not use the code above, if they can you should use the code below instead:

```
public static T GetInHeaderProperty<T>() where T : ISomeType, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    result.CompanyId = "Test";
    result.UserId = "Test";
    result.Password = "Test";
    result.MessageId = " ";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The line `result = (T)resultAsDynamic;` is not needed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, they are needed if the create object function does not create an object that conforms to an interface, which is the case since I assume the two class doesn't share the same interface or base class. See my second alternative if you can get both objects to inherit an interface.

Comment: Hmm...How will I call it? How can I give "Func<T> createObjFunc" parameter to function?

Comment: Not correct. `resultAsDynamic` and `result` both represent the same object. `resultAsDynamic.Password = "Test"; Assert.AreSame(result.Password, "Test");`.

Comment: @anilca, you would call the first one with `GetInHeaderProperty(() => new SomeObject(maybeAParameter))`. This opens up for great flexibility, like when you already have an object you could use: `GetInHeaderProperty(() => existingObject)`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, misunderstanding from me. I thought you meant the first cast, that one is needed, I put the second one in since I just wrote it down with out compile and test to make sure. Removed the last cast. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd have to define an interface or base class with the properties you want to set, specialize your specific types from that, and use generic constraints to let the compiler know that the generic type parameter has those properties.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This code smells. Having 2 types exactly the same but in different namespaces isn't a great idea. Can you move them to a common shared lib?

I see you're using service references. Do you need to have references to each endpoint? Could you somehow refactor your references to remove this duplication?

Comment: In fact they are not my classes, they are coming from several service references.

Comment: No I don't need each of them. I'm just adding these service references for fun. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
public interface IInHeaderType
{
 string CompanyId { get; set; }
 string UserId { get; set; }
 string Password { get; set; }
 string MessageId { get; set; }
}

public static T GetInHeaderProperty<T>() where T : IInHeaderType, new ()
{
        T value = new T();
        // fill the properties of object and return the instance of T
        // I will call it when I need x.InHeaderType or y.InHeaderType
}
```